# Laravel order by for each column?

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to laravel, and i try to `orderBy` the `rand`, is it possible to order by in each  column ? my code just take row rand but it dont shuffle the column just the row.

```
public function show(){
    $name = DB::table('names')
               ->inRandomOrder()
               ->get();

    return view('content', ['names' => $names]);        
}
```

Comment: What does it mean - in each column?

Comment: i want to shuffle for each column and take one string and output i have 5 columns

Comment: Every row in a table is an atomic entity. It's useless to take one column from one row and second column from second row.

Comment: colum 1 shuffle echo string,colum 2 shuffle echo string, etc

Comment: i see, how can i do this with more tables ?

Comment: Please, edit your question with data sample and expected output.

Comment: Why do you need this?

Comment: @AdrianKlark ... Please Update Your Question Soon..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

orderBy in Laravel.

The orderBy method allows you to sort the result of the query by a given column. The first argument to the orderBy method should be the column you wish to sort by, while the second argument controls the direction of the sort and may be either asc or desc:

```
    $users = DB::table('users')
            ->orderBy('name', 'desc')
            ->get();
```

In your case this will work.

```
      public function show(){
       $names = DB::table('names')
      ->orderBy('name', 'desc')
      ->orderBy('city', 'asc')
      ->get();

      return view('content', ['names' => $names]);
```

Answer (score 0):

> You Can Do Like This For To Order by in each column

```
public function show(){
        $names = DB::table('names')
       ->orderBy('name', 'DESC')
       ->orderBy('city', 'DESC')
       ->orderBy('email', 'ASC')
       ->get();

        return view('content', ['names' => $names]);

    }
```

> With `foreach`

```
$names = DB::table('names');

foreach ($request->get('order_by_columns') as $column => $direct) {
    $names->orderBy($column, $direct);
}

$results = $names->get();
```

Comment: i will do it with more tables

Comment: i need to orderbyrand in table but each colum to be shuffle when i echo it to be rand not one row, i can't explain it that well

Comment: i mention in the question i say orderbyrand

Comment: `->random()` try this ??

Comment: `$request` is for request type get ..here

Comment: the variable $request where i define it ??

Comment: Undefined variable: request

Comment: `public function show(Request, $request){ //code }`

Comment: add this header `use Illuminate\Http\Request;`

Comment: i have that i and i take out the comma error but now it says Invalid argument supplied for foreach()